# Delete duplicates based on priority order

Tags: mongodb, duplicates, aggregation-framework, pymongo

Retain a single record from a bunch of duplicates with highest priority while deleting the rest.
All duplicates have the same _id(key) column.

```
db.mycollection.insert([
    {a:1, b:2, c: "ace"},
    {a:1, b:2, c:"queen"},
    {a:1, b:2, c:"jack"},
    {a:0, b:2, c:"king"},
    {a:3, b:2, c:"queen"},
    {a:2, b:2, c:"queen"},
    {a:3, b:2, c:"jack"}
])
```

Here the key is 'a' and the priority is c.
If the value of a is repeated(duplicate) then select the one with highest priority and delete the rest of the duplicates.

I'm a complete mongo noob, so far I've only progressed to finding duplicates. Don't know how I should proceed to delete all except one with most priority.

```
    db.list.aggregate([
        {$group: {
            _id: {a: "$a"},
            uniqueIds: {$addToSet: "$_id"},
            count: {$sum: 1}
            }
        },
        {$match: { 
            count: {"$gt": 1}
            }
         },
    ]);
```

Expected output:

```
{a:1, b:2, c: "ace"}
{a:0, b:2, c:"king"}
{a:3, b:2, c:"queen"}
{a:2, b:2, c:"queen"}
```

The other records with a=1 have been deleted except the one where c=ace, same for a=3 with c=queen. 
a=0,a=2 retained cause no duplicates.